# Vertically aligning images and input fields using relative lengths

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to vertically align to the middle two images, one on the left and one on the right), to a div that will contain one or more label(s) and input field(s). Is it possible to do this using relative lengths only?

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QVdkq/). The image needs to be centered between the label and the field.

Thanks!

HTML

```
<img src="http://lorempixum.com/20/20/abstract" alt=""/>            
<div>
    <label>1234</label>
    <input type"text"/>
</div>
<img src="http://lorempixum.com/20/20/abstract" alt=""/>
```

CSS

```
img, div {
    float: left;
}

label {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easiest way I know:

```
img, div {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[**See fiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/QVdkq/2/), or [**a demo with many labels/inputs**](http://jsfiddle.net/QVdkq/3/).